# Dimensional analysis for a qdf/quantile function corresponing to the pdf/CDF (size distribution of income example)

Tags: probability, integral, dimensions

I am going to frame this question in terms of a pdf and quantile functions for the size distribution of income, because that is where I have currently encountered it, but similar questions in quite different contexts have puzzled me on several occasions in the past.

Suppose I have a pdf `f(x)` or a CDF `F(x)` that represents the size distribution of income. Income is a flow of money (dollars or some unit of currency), per some unit of time, to particular individuals. I therefor think the proper unit of measurement is dollars per person-year.

In order for the probability to come out in dimensionless units, `f(x)` must be measured in person-years per dollar. Integrating this over x also yields a dimensionless share for the CDF because the units of an integral are the product of the units of the integrand `f(x)`, here measured in person-years/dollar, and of the differential `dx`, here measured in dollars/person-year.

Integrating `xf(x)` therefore puts the units on the mean income in $/person-year; this seems reasonable.

From this I have drawn conclusions on the units and interpretation of the quantile density function `q(y)`, quantile function `Q(y)`, and the integral of `yq(y)dy` (i.e. the the inverse function analoge of the partial moment function of order 1) which if correct would be very helpful to me, but in which I have limited confidence. I’d be grateful if someone could confirm or deny these conclusions, perhaps in the context of some discussion/explanation of interpretation of dimensional analysis in the the context of distribution functions.

I believe the units of the y axis and of `q(y)` are necessarily the same as those in the previous analysis, i.e. the y values are still measured in person-years per dollar and `x = q(y)` is still measured in $/person-year. This implies that integrals of `q(y)` over some interval in general, and `Q(y)` (which is equal to the integral of q(y) from 0 to y) in particular, are both measured in unitless shares. I am somewhat dubious of this and my earlier conclusion, however, because I believe that `F(x)` is in unitless shares *of total income,* while `Q(y)` is in unitless shares of *the population for a year.* This seems odd to me, however, as I wonder if the fact that these two shares are *shares of different things* should not be reflected in the units.

Finally, this would have the integral of `yq(y)dy` in units of person-years per dollar. But I am having trouble interpreting this. The corresponding x quantity is the mean (or for a bounded x, the partial mean) of income per person-year. So this would be the mean number of person-years--for what? for a single dollar? for the mean income?

Consider the truncated version of this function, where the integral of `yq(y)dy`from zero to `q*` is divided by `F(q*)`. The corresponding truncated function of x yields the mean for those with incomes of `x*` or less, and $/person-year seems like reasonable units for a mean income. But I want the the y version to come out in number of people, or number of person-years, corresponding to the share of person-years over the same interval, and the "per dollar" in the denominator does not have an interpretation which is obvious to me.

Comment: You need to get the units right.  By definition, the units of $F$ are *probability*.  Thus, the units of $f$ are *probability per (dollars/(person-year))*, or equivalently *probability \* person-year / dollar.*  The dimensional analysis of the PDF is discussed in the duplicate question.

Comment: @whuber In my question above, I also state that the units are person-years per dollar. My confusion is not in regard to the units required to make probability unitless, but with the interpretation of those units as a quantity that is understandable and measurable. For instance, I believe the area between two values under the pdf as a function of $/person-year is the share of total income. It would make my life easier if the area under the quantile density function for the corresponding values was the corresponding population share. But I'm unsure that interpretation is correct.

Comment: It is unclear what your question/problem is, except that your units are messy. What is x and it's units? Then the PDF will have the inverse of those units. The same is true for the quantile function q(y), what is it units? Then get more to the point which quantity is puzzling you. Currently you have a long long story. Put what you have in a table with three columns expression-units-meaning and pinpoint where you do not get it.

Comment: If you like I can edit it into what I get from your question and then you can edit is a second time to make it what your question really is.